# How to iterate through a list without including the same element twice?

Tags: python, list, loops, sum, python-itertools

I was wondering how I could iterate through this list without including the same number twice.

```
import itertools

def sum_pairs(ints, s):
    indexes = []
    pair = []
    for numbers in itertools.combinations(ints,2):
        if sum(numbers) == s:
            pair.append(numbers)
            for n in numbers:
                indexes.append(ints.index(n))
    print(pair)
    print(indexes)

a = [10, 5, 2, 3, 7, 5]
target = 10
```

Here's the output:

```
[(5, 5), (3, 7)]
[1, 1, 3, 4]
```

'pair' correctly outputs 5 and 5 to equal 10, but when I check where the numbers come from with the variable 'indexes', I can see that the same 5 was used twice and the second five was never taken into consideration. What i'm looking for is how can I modify this to not add the same number twice if it's in the same index. For ex. the output of indexes would be [1, 5, 3, 4].

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Smuggle the index of each value along with it by using `enumerate`:

```
import itertools

def sum_pairs(ints, s):
    indexes = []
    pair = []
    for (ix, x), (iy, y) in itertools.combinations(enumerate(ints),2):
        if x + y == s:
            pair.append((x, y))
            indexes += (ix, iy)
    print(pair)
    print(indexes)

a = [10, 5, 2, 3, 7, 5]
target = 10
sum_pairs(a, target)
```

which outputs:

```
[(5, 5), (3, 7)]
[1, 5, 3, 4]
```

To simplify the usage of the values, I unpacked the `tuple` of `tuple`s to names (`x` and `y` are the "real" values, `ix` is the index of `x` and `iy` is the index of `y`). By attaching the index to the value, you always know *exactly* where it came from, without having to guess at it.

Your use of the `index` method didn't work because, for all practical purposes, the two `5` in your input are indistinguishable (on CPython, thanks to the small `int` optimization, they're actually the same object), and `index` just returns the first one it finds (and has to needlessly rescan for it every time). By keeping the index with the associated value, you don't have to recheck at all, you already know it.

Answer (score 2):

Run combination on the index instead. BTW your indexes is defined not-so-commonly. If you got what I meant, try change the 'extend' with an append below

```
def sum_pairs(ints, s):
    indexes = []
    pair = []
    for numbers in itertools.combinations(range(len(ints)),2):
        if ints[numbers[0]]+ints[numbers[1]] == s:
            indexes.extend(numbers)
            pair.append((ints[numbers[0]],ints[numbers[1]]))
    print(pair)
    print(indexes)
```